# Como detectar colisões usando o Slick2D?

Tags: java, objetos, detecção-de-colisão

Gostaria de saber como posso detectar colisões entre objetos usando a slick,tem algum exemplo útil?

Estou fazendo um joguinho simples onde 2 quadrados ficam se movimentando na tela e se o personagem que estou movimentando pelo teclado for atingido por algum dos quadrados, ele volta pra o início da fase

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. A sua pergunta está um pouco geral e assim fica difícil ajudar. Seria possível melhorá-la um pouco? Por exemplo, adicionando informações sobre o que você já tentou, ou sobre que tipo de objetos (são imagens?) está utilizando?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa associar aos objetos que detectarão colisão uma variável do tipo Rectangle (faz parte da Slick2D). Ao construir um Rectangle, os parâmetros x, y, width e height deverão ser dados e sempre que esse objeto se mover, você deve utilizar setBounds para atualizar tais valores.
Como Rectangle extende Shape, você pode utilizar o método intersects da variável do tipo Rectangle passando uma outra Shape (no caso, o rectangle do outro objeto que potencialmente colide) e utilizar a boolean retornada para fazer qualquer processamento baseado nesse evento.

Um exemplo:

```
if (objectA.getRectangle().intersects(objectB.getRectangle())) {
  System.out.println("Colisao detectada");
}
```

Onde objectA e objectB são objetos do seu jogo, que possuem posição e um Rectangle (ou qualquer outra Shape disponível na Slick2D) para ser utilizado como caixa de colisão.
O processamento da colisão depende do tipo de jogo que está sendo feito. Normalmente, não permitimos que a movimentação ocorra caso ela gere uma colisão.

Documentação da classe Rectangle da Slick2D: http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Rectangle.html

Comment: obrigado Thiago irei tentar isso vlw

Comment: Caso minha resposta tenha sido útil não esqueça de aceitá-la. Boa sorte.